# Gatsby deploy on Netlify failed with Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: github, deployment, gatsby, netlify

**Note:** I know there are similar questions with the same error code here on StackOverflow, but their solutions didn't work for me.

---

I'm trying to deploy a Gatsby site on Netlify using GitHub. I followed [the docs from Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/hosting-on-netlify), but my build fails with:

```
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/index.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Bio' in '/opt/build/repo  /src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Bio' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Bio)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/pages/index.js 4:0-36 31:63-66
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/templates/blog-post.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Bio' in '/opt/build/repo  /src/templates'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Bio' in '/opt/build/repo/src/templates'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/t  emplates)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Bio)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Bio.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/templates/blog-post.js 5:0-36 65:44-47
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/index.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Footer' in '/opt/build/r  epo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Footer' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Footer)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Footer.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/pages/index.js 5:0-42 53:29-35
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/404.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/r  epo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Layout)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/pages/404.js 3:0-42 20:31-37
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/index.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/r  epo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Layout)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/pages/index.js 6:0-42 26:31-37
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/templates/blog-post.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/r  epo/src/templates'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Layout' in '/opt/build/repo/src/templates'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/t  emplates)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Layout)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .jsx
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Layout.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/templates/blog-post.js 6:0-42 31:31-37
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/404.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo  /src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Seo)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:         .js
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.jsx doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .wasm
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.wasm doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .json
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.json doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         as directory
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.mjs]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.js]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.jsx]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.wasm]
11:06:04 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.json]
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./src/pages/404.js 4:0-36 23:27-30
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:06:04 PM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM: 
11:06:04 PM:   Error: ./src/pages/index.js
11:06:04 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo  /src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:   resolve '../components/Seo' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
11:06:04 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
11:06:04 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src  /components/Seo)
11:06:04 PM:         no extension
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo doesn't exist
11:06:04 PM:         .mjs
11:06:04 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
11:06:04 PM:           /opt/build/repo/src/components/Seo.mjs doesn't exist
11:06:09 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:06:09 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:06:09 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:06:09 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:06:09 PM: Shutting down logging, 115 messages pending
```

When I google this error message, the solutions seems to be to make sure that the imports are all properly cased. And I checked that and my imports are all properly uppercased:

[image: My components and the import in one file]

And here is a search for the imports:

[image]

As you can see, they are all properly cased. What could be the error?

I'm building with `yarn` if that matters and my build command is `gatsby build`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by [moving the files](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-gotchas/#case-sensitivity) in git using `git mv -f oldName newName`.